# GlassFish не видит Java

Tags: java, glassfish

При попытке запуска GlassFish выдает ошибку

```
GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0
```

echo $JAVA_HOME дает

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

в файле /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/config/asenv.bat добавил строчку

```
set AS_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

в файле /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml java_home не определена

```
<java-config classpath-suffix="" system-classpath="" debug-options="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009">
```

пробовал дописывать

```
java-home="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
```

результата не дало

Спасибо за помощь !

Comment: Какой установки ? :) Во время разархивации архива ?)

Comment: Вот тут эта ошибка и вылазит, как с as-install так и с start-domain

Comment: папка, 159мб. Ну и все остальное работает... Например tomcat

Comment: только что добавлял в /etc/bash.bashrc, ничего не дало

Comment: ребутнулся, непомогло. в файл добавлял  export GLASSFISH_HOME=/opt/glassfish4
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin